# Htaccess with subdomain and zend modules

Tags: .htaccess

I have a Zend Framework application setup using modules. E.G. I have a "stock" module and a "transaction" module. I want to have multiple subdomains for these i.e. stock.website.com, transaction.website.com (so the DocumentRoot will be the same directory for each). The issue is, as they are Zend application 'modules' I would have to go stock.website.com/stock, or transaction.website.com/transaction.

I'm wondering if there's a way to use a rewriteCond rule to identify the subdomain, and then treat all URLs loaded on that page as though they are from stock.website.com/stock, but only having stock.website.com in the adress bar?

At the moment, I have the standard htaccess rules for a zend application.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you could use Zend Route Hostname for your solution as Zend will route the requests (not htaccess) to specific modules based on hostname, so you stresses on query string url would be not an issue then.

Basically, you can add to your application.ini like below (for modules only):

```
resources.router.routes.stock.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
resources.router.routes.stock.route = "stock.yourwebsite.com"
resources.router.routes.stock.defaults.module = "stock"

resources.router.routes.transaction.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
resources.router.routes.transaction.route = "transaction.yourwebsite.com"
resources.router.routes.transaction.defaults.module = "transaction"
```

Then the rest just let Zend handle it.

Hope this would help you!

Comment: @user2041531A small question: When I create the subdomain which folder have to be the subdomain folder root: application/modules/stock? Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1$1
```

The RewriteCond should match `whatever.website.com`
The RewriteRule then maps the URL from `whatever.website.com/path` to `whatever.website.com/whatever/path`.

This ruleset would go between your existing RewriteRules and you would not terminate it with `[L]` so that the index.php rule could act on the resulting URL.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply! Maybe I'm not putting into my htaccess file properly? I put it directly after the `RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]` line, before the index.php directive. It didn't change anything though (and yeah, I did rename website to my site's name).

Comment: That's the right place to put it, but as a test, just to make sure the previous rule isn't interfering, try placing the two lines at the top, just after `RewriteEngine On` and modify the RewriteRule line to redirect (not what you want, but for testing it will allow you to easily see the resulting URL in your browser to make sure the rule is actually matching): `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1$1 [R=301,L]` (the RewriteCond line would remain the same). Also, the usual caveats - restart the server after the change, clear browser cache, and disable mod_cache if it's on to make sure caching isn't an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that still didn't seem to work weirdly enough. I think it must have something to do with how Zend handles module routes. The answer by user2041531 solved the issue, thanks for your help though, I really appreciate it!